# factory AndroidViewModel in jetapck compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

what can I do to pass id(Int) to AndroidViewModel in jetpack compose

viewmodel

```
class RecallViewModel(private val id:Int,application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {

}
```

screen

```
@Composable
fun RecallScreen(
    id:Int,
){
    Text("This is Screen")
}
```

Comment: Are you using [Navigation Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) and the argument support there?

Comment: You actually asking two questions:   1. how to pass id into viewmodel   2. how to pass id from viewmodel to composabe. This is bad practice, you should research each question separetely.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewModel Factory:

```
class ExtraParamsViewModelFactory(
    private val application: Application,
    private val number: Int,
) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return RecallViewModel(number, application)
    }
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val model: RecallViewModel by viewModels {
            ExtraParamsViewModelFactory(this.application, 123)
        }

        setContent {
            Text("This is Screen")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: screen is not activity ,it is composable function